# WPF layout Control issue

Tags: wpf, layout, controls

I have wpf project which print label as per editor. Project has 17 different editors. This is small little drawing for my current application for current label editor.

It has several small controls like, Tool Box, Dimension Slider, Ruler, Canvas navigation bar, Label Definition bar etc... It has one more control called Label Editor, this control will vary as per different editors (17), other controls will stay as it is.

No I want to make some generic control which contains all controls except Label Editor, so each time when I create new editor I don't need to re-create all controls each time. I can use what I have for all 17.

What control should I take to do that, content control, control template, data template or user control for that. Here is small drawing what I have.

[image]

Pls share your suggestions.

Thanks

Dee

Answer (score 0):

You could try loading the label editor through a `Frame` and create a page for each label editor.

Alternatively, you could create a custom control with a `LabelEditor` property that takes an object. This approach would be more difficult, though.